# How to format number in node js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want that if i am given a value like 1k then it should be converted to 1000 or 1m to 100000 and so on..

```
1k - 10000
100k - 100000
1m - 1000000
1b - 1000000000
```

I have searched a lot on the internet, but I can't find any npm package that can do it as well.
i just want a code solution or a npm package to help me in it.

Comment: Create a map of units to coefficients. Parse each input string into its value and unit. Multiply the value by the corresponding unit's coefficient to get the product.

Comment: `const unit = {
 "1k": 10000,
 "100k": 100000,
 "1m ": 1000000,
 "1b": 1000000000,
};
console.log(unit["1k"]);`

Comment: Did you [search](/help/searching) on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```js
var thousand = '1k'
var hundredThousand = '100k'
var hundredThousandComa = '13.5k'
var million = '1m'
var billion = '1b'

var arrayFormat = [thousand, hundredThousand, hundredThousandComa, million, billion]
arrayFormat.map((value) => {
    var number = value.slice(0, -1)
    var last = value.slice(-1)
    if (last == 'k') {
        console.log(number * 1000)
    } else if (last == 'm') {
        console.log(number * 1000000)
    } else if (last == 'b') {
        console.log(number * 1000000000)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a map of units to coefficients.
2. Parse each input string into its value and unit.
3. Multiply the value by the corresponding unit's coefficient to get the product.

Example:

```js
const map = {
  k: 1e3,
  m: 1e6,
  b: 1e9,
  // etc.
};

const inputs = [
  '1k',
  '100k',
  '1m',
  '1b',
];

for (const input of inputs) {
  const value = input.slice(0, -1);
  const unit = input.slice(-1);
  const product = value * map[unit];
  console.log(value, unit, product);
}
```